# MySQLi connection with variables in config.php

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, mysqli

I am creating a database connection class, that will access the variables or constants defined in the config.php. However, if I am going to create a theme and a plugin engine, how would I only allow the MySQLi connection class to access the config without allowing plugins/themes accessing the information breaching the security of the website & users.

Previously, I just defined host, username, password, and database as constants in the config, then included the config inside a file that included all of the core website files, such as the core functions file, database connection, etc - I believe this is how popular CMS's such as Wordpress, etc, does it? If not please correct me.

If I include the config inside the database class, but then include the database class inside the website, the config can be accessed by custom code inside the themes and plugins - which MUST NOT happen.

How would I go about doing this? I cannot think of any other way.

Thanks,
Kieron

Comment: Remember PHP is a is saved as text, if someone wants to look they can. Unless you encrypt the data in whichever file you eventually put it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how would I only allow the MySQLi connection class to access the config

You don't. Instead you should *give* your MySQLi wrapper class all the settings it needs. ie:

```
class MySQLiWrapper {
    public function __construct($server, $username, $password, $database) {..}
}
```

---

As for internal security. PHP code has no sandboxing, any script can do an `fopen` on any file and read it's contents. Think about how you want to approach security.

Comment: To add to this answer. `$wpdb` class (class to interact with db) object is globally available to anything within wordpress scope. Your theme/plugin will not even need to know your db host/user/password/dbname. If they would want to know it, they'd be able to get it. The way to prevent anything bad from happening, is to have a user for wp db which can't be used to connect from a remote host and only has access to wp db without any unneeded privileges.

Comment: So you mean this? $dbc = new dbc($host, $username, $password, $database);

Comment: @IgorYavych So, if a plugin/theme was installed, it can access the database credentials for Wordpress?

Comment: @Kieron yes, they would be able to access defined constants `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, `DB_HOST`